# how can i put variables into if using python, pyomo

Tags: python, if-statement, max, pyomo

### This problem has been solved by the advice of those who are grateful.

I want to simulate using python
Among the necessary constraints, there is a constraint that contains the max function.
I separated it using 'if'.
However, 'if' contains variables and can not be executed.
Could you tell me how to include variables in 'if' or variables in max?

==========================================

```
def comfirststage_rule(model): 

    if (-model.wind1 - model.discharge[1,1] + model.charge[1,1] + model.bidding[1,1]) <= 0.0 :*

        return model.FirstStageCost - model.price[1,1]*model.bidding[1,1] - (model.wind2 +model.discharge[1,1] - model.charge[1,1] - model.bidding[1,1])*model.penalty[1,1] - model.bidding[1,2]*(model.price[1,2] + model.coeffru[1,1]*model.price[1,1]) - model.bidding[1,3]*(model.price[1,3]-model.price[1,1]*model.coeffrd[1,1]) == 0.0
    else:
        return model.FirstStageCost - model.price[1,1]*model.bidding[1,1] + (model.bidding[1,1]-model.discharge[1,1]+model.charge[1,1]-model.wind1)*model.penalty[1,2] - model.bidding[1,2]*(model.price[1,2] + model.coeffru[1,1]*model.price[1,1]) - model.bidding[1,3]*(model.price[1,3]-model.price[1,1]*model.coeffrd[1,1]) == 0.0 

model.comfirststage = Constraint(rule=comfirststage_rule)
```

Produced this error

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint comfirststage: TypeError: Relational expression used in an unexpected Boolean context. The inequality expression: -60 - discharge[1,1] + charge[1,1] + bidding[1,1] <= 0.0
```

Comment: the `if` statement should be able to evaluate any expression you give it... what error are you getting?

Comment: My error message is as follows.
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint comfirststage:
        TypeError: Relational expression used in an unexpected Boolean context.

        The inequality expression:
            -60 - discharge[1,1] + charge[1,1] + bidding[1,1]  <=  0.0

Comment: Well, that error clearly has nothing to do with using variables in an if statement.

Comment: Could this happen because the number of constraints I have entered is insufficient to calculate?

Comment: I read the answer and found that the if statement is not a problem.
I think I need to solve the problem in my pyomo.
Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are any of `model.wind1`, `model.discharge[1,1]`, `model.charge[1,1]`, `model.bidding[1,1]` variables? If so then see this answer from the Pyomo forum:

"Pyomo does not have a mechanism to pass to a solver an if statement involving a Var object. There are modelling tricks (in general, not specific to Pyomo) that one can use to "branch" on values of variables. See, e.g., HP Williams book on modelling among other sources."

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If it is type error then

```
(-model.wind1 - model.discharge[1,1] + model.charge[1,1] + model.bidding[1,1])
```

this code is not clearly comparable to

```
0.0
```

Work on the condition of the if statement and try to reduce problem size like this approach.